# Reverse contents of column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I recently imported access database data into a customers SQL Server database. For one of the tables called 'Cases'; I set up a 'Case_Name' column to be 'Surname Firstname' where 'Surname' and 'Firstname' were columns from the Access database. Now the customer wants the 'Case_Name' column to be 'Firstname Surname' instead. So my question is can this be done in T-SQL nicely or simply or do I need to rerun my c# migration program again or create some other c# program

Current format:

`Cases` table:

```
Id         Case_Name         Case_Description
1          Bloggs Joe        Will Management
2          York Susan        Divorce CAse
```

Want the table to look like this:

```
Id         Case_Name         Case_Description
1          Joe Bloggs        Will Management
2          Susan York        Divorce CAse
```

Comment: can you put a sample of the current table layout and how it should look like after

Comment: I think he wants firstname as prefix for surname..

Comment: Would it not make more sense to have the firstname and surname columns individually, then case_name just becomes a variable in your program which can change as you please.... your design seems inflexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Variant #1**:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , Case_Name NVARCHAR(50)
    , Case_Description NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Case_Name, Case_Description)
VALUES 
    ('Bloggs Joe', 'Will Management'),
    ('York Susan', 'Divorce CAse')

UPDATE @temp
SET Case_Name = SUBSTRING(Case_Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Case_Name), LEN(Case_Name)) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(Case_Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Case_Name)) 

SELECT * FROM @temp
```

**Variant #2**:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , Case_Name NVARCHAR(50)
    , Case_Description NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Case_Name, Case_Description)
VALUES 
    ('Bloggs Joe', 'Will Management'),
    ('York Susan', 'Divorce CAse')

CREATE TABLE dbo.temp
(
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , FirstName NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    , LastName NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    , Case_Name AS FirstName + ' ' + LastName
    , Case_Description NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.temp (FirstName, LastName, Case_Description)
SELECT 
      SUBSTRING(Case_Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Case_Name), LEN(Case_Name)) 
    , SUBSTRING(Case_Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Case_Name)) 
    , Case_Description 
FROM @temp

SELECT * FROM dbo.temp
```

**Output**:

```
ID          FirstName            LastName             Case_Name                                 Case_Description
----------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
1            Joe                 Bloggs                Joe Bloggs                               Will Management
2            Susan               York                  Susan York                               Divorce CAse
```

Comment: UPDATE dbo.Cases
SET Case_Name = SUBSTRING(Case_Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Case_Name), LEN(Case_Name)) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(Case_Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Case_Name))

Answer (score 2):

The safe option is to run your migration program again.

This avoids problems with people have multiple surnames, or multiple firstnames, or both.

A better solution is to have separate columns for surname and firstname.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(casename, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', casename) - 1) AS [FirstName],
SUBSTRING(casename, CHARINDEX(' ', casename) + 1, LEN(casename)) AS [LastName]
```

That will split the 2 out by a space, you can then just concatenate them together however you want.

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName FROM (subquery to get the split as above) as subq
```

As other folks mentioned though, if they have multiple forenames etc, it wouldn't work. Also, store them in separate fields moving forward to make this easier

Comment: You could probably expand the above with a CASE statement to measure if there was more than one space, and to act accordingly, but that is outside of the scope of the question really